# error "Invalid argument:" when using UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) with where date 'yyy-MM-dd'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, urlfetch, google-query-language

I use  [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u78Qx5YIB2mektPyErz6xYtTXMLLtCapXlEpp63NTYI/edit#gid=0) and I want to get the values where the date is > to '2020-07-21',
the data source URL I used with html output is: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u78Qx5YIB2mektPyErz6xYtTXMLLtCapXlEpp63NTYI/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select B where date '2020-07-21' > A &gid=0`

the problem that when I se the data source URL in chrome browser, I could see the response data but when running that with the function UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) I receice an error.
the code in script editor:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var url ="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u78Qx5YIB2mektPyErz6xYtTXMLLtCapXlEpp63NTYI/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&tq=select B where date '2020-07-21' > A &gid=0"
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(); 
    Logger.log(response);
}
```

[image]

Comment: See "What are tags" in [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, there are the following modification points.

#### Modification points:

- Please do the URL encode for `select B where date '2020-07-21' > A`.
- Please request to the endpoint using the access token.

  - In this case, because the data is retrieved, I think that the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` can be used.

When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var query = "select B where date '2020-07-21' > A";
  var url ="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u78Qx5YIB2mektPyErz6xYtTXMLLtCapXlEpp63NTYI/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=" + encodeURIComponent(query) + "&gid=0";
  var params = {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getContentText(); 
  Logger.log(response);
  
  // DriveApp.getFiles()  // This line is used for automatically detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly". So please don't remove this line.
}
```

- When you run the script, the authorization dialog is opened. So please authorize the scopes. By this, the script is run.

#### Note:

- If your Spreadsheet is publicly shared, I think that `params` is not required. At that time, you can remove `// DriveApp.getFiles()`.
- If you want to use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` instead of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`, please use `// DriveApp.createFile()` instead of `// DriveApp.getFiles()`

#### References:

- [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)